# Rebuild React Native Extended StyleSheet?

Tags: react-native

I have an App which has various themes. 
The theme is stored in [Realm JS](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/).

The theme loads when you first start the app. I'm using [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) for styles.

It uses global variable `$theme` for theme color.

User can save a theme & the theme gets saved in [Realm JS](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) but as the StyleSheet builds when you first start the app there is no way the theme changes right after saving. The theme loads when you again restart the app.

```
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';

const getTheme = () => {
   // call realm db & get theme color
}

let theme = getTheme();

EStyleSheet.build({
  $theme: theme,
});

EStyleSheet.subscribe('build', () => {
  theme = getTheme();
});
```

So I need a way to rebuild the StyleSheet when new theme is Saved using [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet). I tried [subscribe method](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet#subscribe) too but I don't know how to use it correctly?

Comment: Did you check the [dynamic-theme-example](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet/tree/master/examples/themes-dynamic) ?

Comment: Yep, but I think my approach is quite simple & achievable. I just don't know how ?

Comment: I posted issue [there](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet/issues/53) too